# JS pass array as arguments to recursive function

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, arguments, apply

Well, again.
I want to call a function inside a recursive function with all the arguments its meant to:

```
function foo(callback /* , callback args */) {
  var args;
  for(var i=1;i<arguments.length;i++) {
    args.push(arguments[i]);
  }
  // somehow set the timeout to foo
  callback.apply(args);
}
```

I already tried to apply to setTimeout too but doesnt seem to work:

```
args.unshift(foo, 100, callback);
setTimeout.apply(args);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array of arguments should be the **second** argument to `apply`.

You need to add an argument to determine the value of `this` before it.

```
setTimeout.apply(window, args);
```